# Use train package for cross validation taking forever in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, r-caret, training-data

my train model contains 8523 data and 15 variables.

[str(my.data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Henlq.jpg)

[session info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKQN4.jpg)
[11] pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.0      bindr_0.1 (these are rest of info from "session info" screenshot)

Before using randomForest, I wanted to use train package for cross validation and finding the optimal value of model parameters.

```
# set tunning parameters
control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)

# random forest model
rf.model <- train(Sales ~ ., data = my.data, method = "parRF", trControl = control, prox = TRUE, allowParallel = TRUE)
```

The session took forever to run, even I used `method = "parRF"`, the parallel implementation of random forest, it still didn't work.

When I switched to use randomForest instead, it had the same issues, the session took forever, and never finished.

```
# random forest model
forest.model <- randomForest(Sales ~ ., data = my.data, mtry = 15, ntree = 1000)
```

Can you see where I have done wrong for both `train()` and `randomForest()`?

Comment: Can you run `str(my.data)` and post the results here so that viewers have a sense of your data?

Comment: Providing a small reproducible example and the results of `sessionInfo` will help get your question answered.

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp str(my.data) is now provided.

Comment: @topepo sessionInfo is now provided.

Comment: can you load `caret` and `randomForest` and do it again?